# iOS On Demand Resources: how to debug

Tags: ios, xcode, on-demand-resources

I would like to test On Demand Resources downloads, possibly with Network Link Conditioner, while debugging the app.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Apple's WWDC15 talk [Introducing On Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-214/?time=2187) specifically addresses this. (Link jumps to 36:27 in the video where debugging info starts.) It's also in the [On Demand Resources Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/TestingPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH21-SW1) in the developer documentation.

The gist: enable Network Link Conditioner on the testing device in Settings > Developer. According to the talk, at least, this affects simulated ODR downloads over USB, not just networked. (On the other hand, the doc seems to contradict this. Try it for yourself! And if it doesn't work for USB... well, testing with own-server-hosted resources can be valuable in itself. Also [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use the Xcode debugger to *view the status* of your on-demand resources, which is very helpful; but unfortunately you cannot *impede* them by pretending that the network is slow or unreliable.

It's a great idea, but the only way you'd be able to do it is to set up your own server to hold the resources, so that the network link conditioner actually does something. (And you are permitted to do this.) As things stand, the resources are in Xcode and are arriving across the USB cable, not the network.